# Why does it generate an error when adding parameters after named parameters?

Tags: dart

look, I have a function with named parameters, but when adding more parameters outside the named parameters it generates an error, the **namesV1** function has no error, but the **namesV0** function has an error, someone knows why .. thank you very much for your help

```
   void namesV0(String name1 , {String  name2 ='NotFound'}, String name3 , int edad) {}
void namesV1(String name1 , String name3, int edad, {String  name2 ='NotFound'}) {}
```

Comment: Unnamed parameters are order-dependent.  Named parameters are order-independent.  Mixing the two doesn't make a lot of sense, would be unnecessary and would be potentially confusing/error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because you have added optional argument in between the method:

Good practice says optional arguments should be placed in last at arguments list.
That is the reason why your namesV1() function is running fine and namesV0() is not.

Check this for more detail: https://zaiste.net/posts/dart-optional-function-parameters/

[image]